# How practical is a laser microphone and how to protect against it?

Tags: hardware, surveillance, audio

A laser microphone is a "surveillance device that uses a laser beam to detect sound vibrations in a distant object". - [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_microphone).

It's also known as a Laser Based Listening System (LBLS).

[image: Laser Based Listening System]

Firstly, how practical or easy is it to use a laser microphone for surveillance and how effective is it?

Secondly, what can you do to protect against such surveillance? *I've heard something about vibrating windows.*

Thirdly, are there known cases wherein this was or is effectively used?

Lastly, in what circumstances (like weather, distance, target material) can this device be used?

### Some examples

1. *I found a webshop that used to sell this device: [https://www.dpl-surveillance-equipment.com/2181255.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20130323032408/https://www.dpl-surveillance-equipment.com/2181255.html).*
2. *I found another device sold here: https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Laser-Listening_50011848821.html with a demonstration video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NuyMRp0yc4w.*
3. *Also, this video demonstration seems impressive: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h7O-xiZcOAo*

Comment: Pure speculation: If you play loud music (or, even better, random noise) in the room and only talk quietly (with people sitting close together), it seems likely that the technique won't work. (If it works at all.)

Comment: @5gon12eder Maybe, I have added one URL to a web shop that used sell it.

Comment: Whoa they have been using stuff like this since Leon Theremin build one before 1947, the first I heard of the idea was in William Gibson's book published in 1986. To protect against listening devices I'd just avoid using sound for communicating, and just write down what you wanted to say on some paper.

Comment: In the series burn notice they remove the IR filter from a camera to detect them and use a massager to create vibrations on the window to 'jam' them. I can speak from experience with IR devices that most phone cameras can detect the frequency used by the device you have linked.

Comment: There was a research project... I wish I could remember the name... they reconstituted sounds from a silent low quality video by detecting vibration of the subject of the video (a plant or some such).   It was terrible sound reproduction, but you could make out the bits of 'mary had a little lamb'.  More on topic - music is a known quantity and could possibly be filtered.  Noise on the other hand is random enough that quiet conversations aren't recoverable. Ideally - randomly play 1000 simultaneous conversations near the window and talk quietly.

Comment: This is why the TLAs (three-letter agencies) use transducers to play music into their exterior glass.

Comment: @JeffK probably is talking about [this](http://people.csail.mit.edu/mrub/VisualMic/) or similar work. While I wouldn't call a high speed video from an expensive camera or at least modern DSLR "low quality" it demonstrates that sound can be indeed reconstructed from filming moving surfaces inside a room. Make sure to implement countermeasures against that too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Laser Microphones like any other eavesdropping equipment has pros and cons.

**Pros**

- Can be invisible if using infra-red (IR) beam
- Will not be detected with typical radio frequency (RF) finders
- Can be turned on/off at will - avoiding further detections

**Cons**

- The beam (laser or other) needs to be in within line of sight of the target
- Is affected by rain / snow (more explanation below)
- IR beam can be easily detected using the [Front-Facing Camera on an iPhone](http://www.instructables.com/id/See-Infrared-LED-Light-with-an-iPhone-4/)

**Recent History**

These devices were all the rage in the 90s - you can see this by seeing the style of websites selling them ([here](http://www.bestlasermicrophones.com/ourproduct.html) and [here](http://www.electromax.com/laser.html) are examples)

For a while they fell out of favor with the rise of networking/computer eavesdropping technologies which provided more value per dollar.

Recently though, they have been having a semi-resurgence with anti terror units having use for them. [Here](http://argoasecurity.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=263) is an example of one such company marketing it.

**Laser Microphone History**

The earliest recording of a "Laser" microphone is by an inventor named [Léon Theremin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9on_Theremin).

He created something named the Buran eavesdropping system which essentially used an low powered infra-red beam to detect vibrations made by sound-waves. He demonstrated this device on a pane of glass.

**Operating Principles**

Laser microphones work by shining a light on an object that vibrates (think: glass, plastic cup etc.) When someone speaks (or any other noise is introduced) it pushes the air around it causing the object that the laser is shining on to vibrate.

When the object vibrates it causes minute differences in the distance traveled by the light as it reflects back to a receiver. These difference are detected using something called [Interferometry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interferometry).

These signals are then translated back into sound which allow you to hear what is going on.

**Mechanics - the moving parts**

Here are the pieces involved to make this work:

*Laser beam*

This is the device that will 'shine a light' on the object in the room (or on the window. Modern versions of these systems can work at distances of [500 meters](http://argoasecurity.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=263)

*Receiver*

This is the device that picks up the reflection of the beam typically placed at about a 90 degree angle to the originating beam. It processes the reflected light signal and sends it to the next piece of electronics for processing.

*Demodulator*

This is the device that actually turns it into sound for you. This device can be controlled with software to remove noises such as wind etc. to provide a clearer sample.

**A Laser Microphone can be pretty effective if used properly and in ideal conditions**

But remember that the information you are looking for may be in a digital device and not in voice spoken format.

**Countermeasures**

Detecting a Laser microphone is relatively easy in many cases (mentioned earlier in the answer)

Vibrating the windows is not always effective as software can (and has) been written to remove the frequency from the vibrating noises.

However, one can create a device that vibrates the windows with frequencies that used typically in human speech. Such a device could if done correctly render the laser microphone useless.

**Known cases of use**

Though there isn't any official documentation of its use, there are some places that discuss its use during the cold war ([here](http://hackaday.com/2015/12/08/theremins-bug/) is an example).

There has also been speculation whether [government agencies used such a device during the Snowden investigation](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/aug/22/gchq-warned-laser-spying-guardian-offices).

**Usage Limitations**

In order for this system to work you need line-of-sight to an object that vibrates.

This object obviously has to be within reasonable distance to the source of the noise.

Rain, Snow or any other weather that interferes with an IR beam would affect the ability to eavesdrop.

One last thing to mention is the need for both the shining laser and the receiver to be stationary the whole time and not move. Usually, this is achieved by using a pair of tripods (like in the image posted in the question)

**Some interesting links**

http://www.instructables.com/id/Laser-Surveillance-System-for-under-%2420/

http://hackaday.com/2010/09/25/laser-mic-makes-eavesdropping-remarkably-simple/

http://lifehacker.com/5961503/build-a-laser-microphone-to-eavesdrop-on-conversations-across-the-street

http://www.lucidscience.com/pro-laser%20spy%20device-1.aspx

https://web.archive.org/web/20180305115138/http://www.williamson-labs.com/laser-mic.htm

Comment: As a side note - certain frequencies of IR light cannot be detected by the iPhone camera, or other cell phone cameras for that matter.

Answer (score 5):

AS A USER OF THIS TECHNOLOGY (no, LeRoy Theremin did not use this since lasers were not developed until Theodore Maiman made the first laser operate on 16 May 1960 at the Hughes Research Laboratory in California) I can firmly state that IF the window is firmly installed and not rattling loosely in its frame, that with computer audio filtering, it is very easy to pick out individual voices in a loud cacophony, that includes very loud music. Ive used it to make very high fidelity recordings of concert environments that included conversational elements  of the audience.

Comment: You personally used a laser microphone in an concert environment? Could you elaborate? (BTW: what a rude audience.)

Comment: How to protect against it?

Comment: Move all the offices to the interier of the building, away from the windows and make the perimeter of building a talkway. On top of that, put diffusers on the windows too so the laser from outside can't hit any office window.

Comment: "talkway" or "walkway"? If "talkway", can you define that, please?

Comment: I learned recently Europeans have nicer working conditions where by law their offices have to have a window, or at least a sun roof!

Answer (score 4):

I am not as experienced as ScottS in the use of this apparatus, but I understand the basic concept of it.

I think that ScottS answers your first question better than I can.  As long as there is a firmly mounted glass window, and the internal noise is louder than a whisper, then the device should be able to pick it up.

There are several ways I can think of to protect against this type of surveillance.  The thing you mentioned about vibrating windows is correct; you can essentially mount a small vibrating motor or speaker to each window, which will create enough vibration to drown out the movement caused by internal sound waves.  Another thing you can do is to have some sort of a wire screen or curtain on the outside of the window, which interferes with the laser beam.  The best option, though, is to simply not have windows in sensitive rooms.  Even if a laser can't pick up vibrations, a powerful camera may be able to read lips, or other things like that.  Windows, in general, are insecure.  (Not to mention that it is a lot easier to break into a room that has a window in it.)

As far as the historical use of this goes, I am not an expert in spy history, but it seems that it has been used in real life espionage by both the US and Russia.  Apparently the US embassy in Russia was designed with curtain walls to prevent this type of spying.  I don't have any specific instances for you, though.

For your last question, it seems that the only requirement is that the laser is able to reflect back to the sensor, with enough strength for the sensor to detect it.  So I can see it easily working from over 100 ft away, as long as the laser is powerful enough.  The weather shouldn't matter, as long as the sensor is shielded from direct sunlight.  (But snow or rain may interfere, as they would occasionally block the beam of the laser.  The recording would probably still be intelligible, but would have a lot of static.)  As far as target material, I have seen it used on materials other than glass, but the material must be reflective.  Otherwise the laser beam never gets back to the sensor.  Also, it must be relatively smooth, because any bumps will distort the vibrations.

By the way, I found a very interesting project [here](http://hackaday.com/2010/09/25/laser-mic-makes-eavesdropping-remarkably-simple/) that explains how to make a simple device for yourself.